# Two nested async.each calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

I have the following method:

```
mergeAinBbyAttr: function(a, b, attr1, attr2, val, cb) {
    var result = [];
    async.each(a, function(itemA, cb1) {
        async.each(b, function(itemB, cb2) {
            if (itemA[attr1] == itemB[attr1]) {
              itemB[attr2] = val;
            }
            result.push(itemB);
            cb2(null, result);
          },
          function(e, result) {
            sails.log('[result]', result);
            cb1(e, result);
          });
      },
      function(e, result) {
        cb(e, result);
      });
  }
```

I basically want to compare an array of objects (A) to another array of objects (B), and return an updated array (C) with every item in B, but updates with attributes from A.

The above [result] returns undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is all synchronous code, so you don't need async module, you just need regular looping constructs. But let's assume you need async.

Use `async.map` instead of `async.each`, for more brevity:

```
mergeAinBbyAttr: function(a, b, attr1, attr2, val, cb) {

    async.map(a, function(itemA, cb) {
        async.map(b, function(itemB, cb) {
            if (itemA[attr1] === itemB[attr1]) {
              itemB[attr2] = val;
            }
            cb(null, itemB);

          },cb);

      },cb);
  }
```

you do not need to name the cb variables different names, because they have different scopes.

If you want a flattened array at the end of this routine, I would recommend using `_.flatten` or `_.flattenDeep` from lodash or underscore.

Note that this:

```
function(e, result) {
   cb(e, result);
});
```

can just be reduced to:

```
cb
```

=================================

Doing this with synchronous methods:

```
    mergeByAttr: function(a, b, attr1, attr2, val) {

      return a.map(function(itemA){
          return b.map(function(itemB){
                if (itemA[attr1] === itemB[attr1]) {
                  itemB[attr2] = val;
                }
                return itemB;
           });

      });
   }
```

As you can see, either way, you will get nested arrays, it has nothing to do with the async module, but the nature of your code.

The more performant, but less functional way:

```
     mergeByAttr: function(a, b, attr1, attr2, val) {

          a.forEach(function(itemA){
              b.forEach(function(itemB){
                    if (itemA[attr1] === itemB[attr1]) {
                      itemB[attr2] = val;
                    }
                    return itemB;
               });

          });
       }
```

Comment: Thank you! But now it returns an array of B for every A.

Comment: Right, so flatten it with _.flatten()

Comment: Also, you really don't need async module for this code, you can use Array.prototype.map => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Isn't there more efficient way to do it without flattening it a the end, just loop through it, if found update the attribute? I feel like im drowning in a glass of water with this

Comment: yes, but with functional programming, you don't want a function that just mutates data; you want to return new data from the function. Array.prototype.map will return a new array.

Comment: You can use forEach() instead of map() but this is less functional. Enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks, duly noted!

Comment: In general however, the async module is the most powerful utility for Node.js code; I believe it is more powerful than promises and is simpler than Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Well I watched That the answer above help you, only I want highlight one thing about your error:

[result] returns undefined.

is because according to documentation, the optional function only has 1 parameter, and you are trying to get 2 parameter: function(e, result)

http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Comment: right, async.each does not yield anything except errors, async.map yields both an error and results array.